# How can I remove this black theme from firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, themes, fedora-23

I just updated my Fedora distro from 21 to 23 and now firefox has a black theme that is nice but prevents me from seeing what I am writing for passwords on several site (see SO login)
[image]

I changed the theme to a white one using `customize` but only the tabs are changing color (see bellow)
[image]
It might be a fedora option I am a bit puzzled

Comment: I think you are using Firefox Developer Edition. Is that right? That looks like the built-in dev version theme.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, I was using a tweek at fedora level to force dark theme on all apps. Removing the option solved it

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution!

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).